# YQL + TABLE + XPATH

Tags: xpath, yql

I'm working with YQL. I understand how to make a simple query to a web page and select content with xpath.

For example: `select * from html where url="http://www.animeclick.it/manga.php?xtit=Ranmaru+XXX"` and `xpath="/html/body/div/table/tr/td/table/tr/td/div/div/img[contains(@src,'manga')]"`.

Now, there are limitation in this approach. I can't make login to the site, can't repeat different information in the page (I know can make more query or add new xpath expression) and I can't format output result

```
(like inside div this content : 
    "<p> Hello <a src="#"> Boy!</a></p>" ,
    where in this case i need the text "Hello boy")
```

How to use YQL OPEN TABLE for this scope!??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use YQL OPEN TABLE for this scope!??!

Please take the time to have a thorough read through the [**Creating YQL Open Data Tables**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql_dev_guide.html) chapters in the YQL docs.

In particular, an `<execute>` block ([docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-execute-chapter.html)) will enable you to do all of the things that you mentioned above.